# Huge Response time in Load runner

Tags: loadrunner

Huge Response time found in loadrunner for single iteration, this huge response time not found in manually. Application Microsoft CRM 365. Recorded in http/html mode.

Comment: Then you are measuring different things.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple parameters why LoadRunner's transaction time is longer as compared manually. Three important points which would help you

- Replay in VuGen may have additional delay as it is running in debug mode.
- When accessing a page manually and it looks finished, more information/resources may still be downloaded on the background . For example, a long page could finish displaying the top half that can be seen, and so looks finished, but it is still downloading the portions of the page you have to scroll to see. When timing a page's manual performance, check that the browser icon in the top right has stopped being animated, AND that the status bar in the bottom left shows "Done." LoadRunner times the loading of the complete page, and the page is not complete until these two indicators show so.
- The browser may be caching, say, 50 images. When client (browser) make a request, data is retrieved from the cache and not from the server. This is different with LoadRunner even if you have caching turned on, as LoadRunner's cache is empty each time you run a script. LoadRunner build up the cache as you execute the script.

Reference: https://community.microfocus.com/t5/LoadRunner-Professional-User/High-Respnse-Time-Visible-through-Vugen-Performance-Centre/td-p/571147